# HtmlHelper.Display() & DisplayFor() not working as expected for a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view for editing a client with the line:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x=>x.Orders)
```

in it. But it **only** outputs a display for the Id property,  ignoring the other properties:

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Order Header")]
    public string Header { get; set; }

    // ... etc...

}
```

whereas I expect the behaviour to be:

> If the object contains multiple properties, for each property the method generates a string that consists of markup for the property name and markup for the property value. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

What have I missed?

the view:

```
@model Models.Client

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Client Details";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<fieldset>
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Notes, "ListOfNotes")
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("NewNoteForm", Model); }
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  @using(@Html.BeginForm())
  {
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
  }
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Orders) @* The errant bit *@
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  @{ Html.RenderPartial("NewOrderForm", Model); }
</fieldset>
```

The Client Model:

```
public class Client
{
    public Client(int PId, string title, string forename, string surname)
        : this()
    {
        PId = pId;
        Title = title;
        Forename = forename;
        Surname = surname;
    }

    public Client()
    {
        Notes = new List<Note>();
        Orders= new List<Order>();
    }

    public int PId { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; private set; }
    public List<Order> Orders { get; private set; }
}
```

Btw, The list of notes displays as expected.

Comment: Can you show us the view you're using, and its model type ?

Comment: What Version of MVC are you using? Could this be a latter feature?

Answer (score 1):

Either Use `Html.DisplayForModel(o=>o)`

or call `Html.DisplayFor()` 
for each property of your current model. Something like this.

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Id)
@Html.DisplayFor(model=>model.Header)
```

Comment: That does seem to contradict the quoted MSDN article? Or am I reading it wrong?

Comment: Arguably where the article says "If the *object* contains multiple properties, for each property ..." we are wanting to read it as "If the *property* recursively contains multiple properties, for each property .." - but recursive generation of display for properties of  properties is what we expect isn't it?

Comment: @Parv, yes I can get it working by creating a DisplayTemplate Order.cshtml and typing all the markup, BUT what I want to understand is why I have to do that

Comment: @ChrisFCarroll - ill get back to you as soon as i reach my desk

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it in a new empty project later today

Answer (score 0):

Since `Orders` is a list, you need a loop to display all the items in that list, like this:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName(m => m.Title)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayName(m => m.Orders)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Title)</td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var order in Model.Orders)
                {
                    <div>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(_ => order)
                    </div>
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The quote:

> If the object contains multiple properties...

refers to the fact the `order` object's properties (`Id` and `Header`) should be displayed all at once, using that single `@Html.DisplayFor(_ => order)` line.